# Change onclick Attribute While Composing DIV Tag Within Prototype

Tags: javascript, html, oop, prototype

I have the following code in Javascript. As you can see, I have a general class called ICeCream from which 3 other classes inherit. I would like to make it so the method displayEntity() prepares a div tag for display. It seems to work except for one issue. The issue is that I cannot seem to get the onclick property to work. It either contains "undefined" in the resulting HTML or has the following code

```
function() {
alert(this.name + " clicked!")}
```

My ultimate goal is to have an HTML div tag whose "onclick" contains a method from the respective object. That is, when different div's are clicked, different methods of different objects should be invoked. How can I achieve this?

Here is the main code:

```
    //Implementation of inheritance between objects
function inheritPrototype(childObject, parentObject) {
            // So the copyOfParent object now has everything the parentObject has ​
            var copyOfParent = Object.create(parentObject.prototype);
            //Then we set the constructor of this new object to point to the childObject.​
            // Why do we manually set the copyOfParent constructor here, see the explanation immediately following this code block.​
            copyOfParent.constructor = childObject;
            // Then we set the childObject prototype to copyOfParent, so that the childObject can in turn inherit everything from copyOfParent (from parentObject)​
            childObject.prototype = copyOfParent;
}


//General IceCream object
function IceCream (name, description){
    this.numberScoops = 0;
    this.flavors = [];
    this.numberSoda = 1;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.cssID = this.name.replace(/\s+/g,'');
}


IceCream.prototype.click = function() {
    alert(this.name + " clicked!")
}

IceCream.prototype.displayEntity = function(object){
    var itemToDisplay = "";

    itemToDisplay += '<div id="' + this.cssID + '" class="menuitem" value="" onclick="">' + '<h2>' + this.name + '</h2>' + '&nbsp;' + this.description + '<div>';


//  itemToDisplay += '<div id="menuitem" value="" mousedown="<script>' + this.click + '</script>">' + '<h2>' + this.name + '</h2>' + '&nbsp;' + this.description + '<div>';


    itemToDisplay += "<br>";

    console.log (itemToDisplay);
    console.log(this);
    //document.getElementById("Menu").innerHTML += itemToDisplay;

    return itemToDisplay;
}

//Declare Cone object
function Cone(name,description){
        IceCream.call(this,name,description);
}
//Cone inherits from IceCream
inheritPrototype(Cone, IceCream);

//Declare Milkshake object
function MilkShake(name, description){
        IceCream.call(this,name,description);
}
//Milkshake inherits from IceCream
inheritPrototype(MilkShake, IceCream);

//Declare Float object
function Float(name, description){
        IceCream.call(this, name, description);
}
//Float inherits from IceCream
inheritPrototype(Float, IceCream);
console.log("Code ran;")

var Menu = [new Cone("Cone","Waffle Cone with 1-2 Scoops"), new MilkShake("Delicious Milkshake", "Milkshake with Skim, Whole or 2% Milk"), new Float("Ice Cream Float", "Any number of scoops and flavors, one soda")];

// Display all the questions​
    Menu.forEach(function (eachItem)  {
            document.getElementById("Menu").innerHTML += eachItem.displayEntity(eachItem);
});
```

Comment: `mousedown="<script>' + this.click + '</script>"` is completely invalid HTML.

Comment: Use [proper event handlers](http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html), and [bind them appropriately](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572).

Comment: I have tried multiple variations of the code, including what you have above. The problem is that this.click comes as "undefined."

Comment: You should return a DOM element instead of the HTML string and use `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML +=`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to have worked. :-)

Comment: Do you know whether there is a way to use appendChild and insert multiple divs? With my current usage, it seems to only add a single div, which is the last one to be called using appendChild().

Comment: Just call `appendChild` multiple times. Make sure to append different divs, not the same element over and over.